# Laravel JSON reading from POST

Tags: php, json, backbone.js, laravel-4

Suppose I have a resourcefull route in Laravel 4.1, like next:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api',], function()
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
    Route::resource('user','UserController');
});
```

And I have controller method `store()` like next:

```
    public function store()
    {
        $user = new User;
        $name = Input::get('name');
        $user->login_name = implode('.', explode(' ', strtolower($name)));
        $user->name = $name;
        $user->email = Input::get('email');
        $user->password = Hash::make('1');
//      $user->save();
        return Response::json([
                'error' => false,
                'user' => $user->toArray()
                ], 200);

    }
```

I am making post request either from backbone, or just from rest api test tool: the request is following:

```
{"phone":"123123123","description":"","name":"test","email":"test@test.com"}
```

The problem is that when I look at the response I see that request was empty :

```
{"error":false,"user":{"login_name":"","name":null,"email":null}}
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: is $user->save() saving properly to DB?

Comment: no, gives the error that field "name" is empty

Comment: what HTTP method are you using? GET, POST, PUT?

Comment: POST of course, and If I read php://input then there is 2 json strings(same)

Comment: what do you get when you try dd($name) in the store() method

Comment: For the post request you are passing the json object as one variable to method. What was the result when you do dd(Input::all()) ?

Comment: I get null for all of them

Comment: Can you post or upload a screenshot of your request from your rest test tool ?

Comment: Can you do this, just a test.. ? in the post, send the json as data : {{"phone":"123123123","description":"","name":"test","email":"test@test.com"} }.. then do dd(Input:all())

Comment: Same result , here http://d.pr/i/paoN

Comment: Did u try Input::json()->all() ?

Comment: yes, some time before the rertieving from php://input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the following header in your request

```
content-type:application/json
```

or alternatively you can set it in the "App::before" filter

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    $request->headers->set('content-type','application/json');
});
```